# Python sys.argv limits on character types

Tags: command-line, sys

This has been mentioned in other questions, but there hasn't been a specific answer. I would like to pass in, through the command line, this:

```
python 1.py generatemaze 5 5 <11
```

When I try this, however, the '<11' is not recognized, and sys.argv looks like this:

```
['1.py', 'generatemaze', '5', '5']
```

Is there some kind of character type limitation inherent in sys.argv, or is this peculiar to my computer? I'm running on Yosemite.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your shell, but most that I know use `<` and `>` to redirect input and output. You might try  `python 1.py generatemaze 5 5 "<11"`.

Comment: Great, thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<` operator in bash is a way of piping in a file/value into your program (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). You can get around this by wrapping your <11 between "", or escaping the < such as `\<11`.